# how to save image using <input type = "file"> into oracle database using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, oracle

I could display an oracle database blob image in an `<img>` tag using the handler but all what I want to know how to insert the uploaded image using input of type file
and I have this form enclosing  (BaladiaInfo.aspx is the name of the page)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="BaladiaInfo.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form>
```

this is my input and img partitions

```
    <img src="Handler2.ashx" id="BlobImg"  />  

  <input type="file" name="FileUploaad" id="Browse" s/>
```

and I have a button at the bottom of the page that updates the page controls values plus the new browsed image

```
<div id="SaveButtons" class="actions" style="text-align: center;">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="save" Width="100" Style="font-size: 20px"
                                    OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
```

I want the code that enables me to update the blob image in database